# stop from outputting one item in dynamic ul list in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dynamic ul list from a database being outputted as categories however there is one category I don't want listed in this particular list. Is there a sql select that stops from showing one value in the field? or can I write an if statement after the select query that targets the list to not show that one item? 
If anyone can help then I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What about this one item is special? You want to skip it by name, by a flag, or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL provides `where` clauses for you to filter the results you're selecting.

Assuming your table is called `category` and its primary key is `id`, add something along the lines of `where category.id != <id of category you don't want>` to your query. If you already have a `where` clause, append another condition with `and` instead: `and category.id != ...`.